# Parallel processing of List<Mono<Object>> using Reactive

Tags: list, parallel-processing, mono, flux, reactive

I have a method which iterates through items from cart and places an order for the same using placeOrder. 
Once placeOrder is called for all the items in the cart, I want to consolidate and send a single Mono Object summarizing what order went through and which one did not

This code works but is not using parallel execution of placeOrder.

```
List<Mono<OrderResponse>> orderResponse = new ArrayList<Mono<OrderResponse>>();
        OrderCombinedResponse combinedResponse = new OrderCombinedResponse();
//placeIndividualOrder returns Mono<OrderResponse>
        session.getCartItems().forEach(cartItem ->
          orderResponse.add(placeIndividualOrder(cartItem)));

return Flux.concat(orderResponse).collectList().map(responseList -> {
            responseList.forEach(response -> {
//Do transformation to separate out failed and successful order

            });
//Return Mono<OrderCombinedResponse> object
            return combinedResponse;
        });
```

I am trying the below code to work to have the orders in cart processed in parallel but it does not return any response and just exits

```
//Return Mono<OrderCombinedResponse> object 
return Flux.fromIterable(session.getCartItems()).parallel()
//Call method to place order. This method return Mono<OrderResponse>
.map(cartItem -> placeIndividualOrder(cartItem))
.runOn(Schedulers.elastic())
//
.map(r -> {
                    r.subscribe(response -> {
                        //Do transformation to separate out failed and successful order

                    });
                    return combinedResponse;
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

since method `placeIndivisualOrder()` returns `Mono`, you need to call it with `.flatMap()`. The `.runOn()` should go above the call to `placeIndivisualOrder()`. If it goes after, like in your code above, you make only the subsequent `.map()` run on the scheduler. Finally, instead of calling `subscribe()` inside of `.map()` like you do, you should just call `.subscribe()` after `.flatMap()`:

```
return Flux.fromIterable(session.getCartItems()).parallel()
    .runOn(Schedulers.elastic())
    //Call method to place order. This method return Mono<OrderResponse>
    .flatMap(cartItem -> placeIndividualOrder(cartItem))
    .sibscribe(response -> {
         // do something with response
    },
    e -> {
         // catch and report error
    })
```